# Character counting from big files in assembly

Tags: file, assembly, size, character

This should be counting every character in file but its working only for smaller files and i need it to work for files containing more than 32768 characters

```
fn DB strsize DUP ('$');
bsize equ 32768
buff db bsize dup ('$')


read proc
        mov ah,3dh ;open
        mov al,0 ; read only mode
        mov dx,offset fn ; offset of file name
        int 21h ; file handle
        jc jmpchyba
        ret
        endp

BITY proc       
        mov full,00
        mov actual,00

jmpback:
        call read
        mov actual,00
        mov bx,ax;offset buff
        mov ah,3fh
        mov cx,bsize ; count bytes
        mov dx,offset buff
        int 21h ; 

        mov actual,ax
        mov bx,actual
        add full,bx

        cmp actual,bsize
        je jmpback  
        vypis kolko

        mov ax,full
        call convasci;this is working convert from binary to asci   

        ret
        endp
```

Comment: You should either use 32-bit register, or 16-bit registers pair. For example, DX:CX

Comment: Im working on it but i dont know how it was formated until I posted it here

Answer (score 1):

Firstly define *full* as a dword. Then use this code

```
mov actual,ax
mov bx,actual
add full,bx
adc full+2,0
```

Obviously the conversion routine *convasci* should also be changed to deal with a dword.

The proc *read* actually **opens** the file! You should certainly not keep calling it from the *BITY* proc.
Rename *read* as *open* and place `call open` before the label *jmpback:*

```
Open proc
 mov ah,3dh ;open
 mov al,0 ; read only mode
 mov dx,offset fn ; offset of file name
 int 21h ; file handle
 jc jmpchyba
 ret
endp

BITY proc       
 mov full,0
 mov full+2,0
 call Open
 mov bx,ax ;Handle!!!
jmpback:
 mov actual,00
 mov ah,3fh
 mov cx,bsize ; count bytes
 mov dx,offset buff
 int 21h ; 

 mov actual,ax
 add full,ax
 adc full+2,0

 cmp ax,bsize
 je jmpback
```

Comment: Ive tried it but Its doing exactly the same thing as mine code

Comment: I changed it as you adviced but now its returning 32774 which is not correct

Comment: Did you apply changes to `mov ax,full` and `call convasci` ?

Comment: Convasci should be able to deal with dword which changes do you mean with mov ax,full?

Comment: Either code `mov eax,full` or use 2 registers like `mov ax,full` `mov dx,full+2`